# Javascript - iOS onclick not working correct on an element

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, onclick

I created an a element with two `onclick` actions:

```
<a id="richiesta" value="Remove" class="btn-step" onclick="remove(); ga('send', 'event', 'add', 'add', 'add');" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>/invia">
Invia
</a>
```

and I create remove function on js:

```
function remove(){<br>
    setTimeout(function(){<br>
    jQuery("#richiesta").hide();<br>
    jQuery("#descr").hide();<br>
    jQuery("#loader").show();<br>
    jQuery("#richiesta").attr('href','');<br>
    }, 10);<br>
    return true;<br>
}
```

`onclick` works greatly on desktop mode, but not the same as mobile mode (especially on iOS). Can you help me to find a solution?

I read different solutions about this theme, but don't work (for example add to css cursor: pointer on a element doesn't work).

Comment: is it about Cordova or PhoneGap?? Why are you using `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: br elements on function code is an error that not have original code